# Unable to install NuGet Packages due to Incompatibility

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012, nuget, azure-mobile-services

I can't seem to install the Windows Azure Storage NuGet Package because the version clashes with another package that probably depends on it. I can't seem to install anything related Azure because the same error pops up every time.

> Install failed. Rolling back... Updating 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.2'
>   to 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4' failed. Unable to find versions of
>   'WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables,
>   WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity' that are compatible with
>   'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4'.

Why do I get this and how can I get around to having all compatible versions?

Comment: Have your tried to manually upgrading OData Services to 5.6.4? and then try to install Azure Storage nuget?

Comment: Try using the Azure App Service packages instead of MobileServices. Check out this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services/